# Iterate over a vector to update a word_counter

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, boost-multi-index

I have a vector of Result structures, each of which contains a contract string that is a "word"

```
struct Result
    {
        string contract;
        int score;
    };
```

I want to find the frequency of occurrence of the distinct words in the vector.

I can concatenate them all into a single piece of text using a separator and extract the frequency from that

```
text_tokenizer tok(text, separator);

for (text_tokenizer::iterator it = tok.begin(), it_end = tok.end();
    it != it_end; ++it)
{
    ++total_occurrences;
    word_counter::iterator wit = wc.insert(*it).first;
    wc.modify_key(wit, ++bl::_1);
}
```

using a multi_index_container

```
typedef multi_index_container
<
    word_counter_entry,
    indexed_by
    <
    ordered_non_unique
    <
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(
        word_counter_entry, unsigned int, occurrences),
    std::greater<unsigned int>
    >,
    hashed_unique
    <
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(word_counter_entry, std::string, word)
    >
    >

> word_counter;
```

But it seems cleaner to iterate over the raw vector

```
for (std::vector<Result>::iterator it = begin(v); it != end(v); ++it)
    {
        //Magically update word counter 
    }
```

Any appropriate piece of magic much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a map with the word as the key and the frequency (count) as the value.

```
std::map<std::string, int> frequency;
for (auto& result : v) {
    frequency[result.contract]++;
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed.  I was trying to use Boost functionality and avoid custom code but what you suggest is so much simpler!